# Create single string from other strings

Tags: matlab

I have a variable which is the list of string of a listBox handle

```
string = get(handles.ListBox,'string');
string=
       'file1'
       'file2'
```

I want to create a single string like:

```
line= 'file1 file2'
```

In order to write it in one line in my output file. The number of input files may vary in every case so I would like to do it in a general way.  I have tried 'horzcat', 'strcat' but no success.

Comment: Why don't you accept an answer?

Answer (score 6):

There is a [`strjoin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strjoin.html) function specifically for this task:

```
C = {'one', 'two', 'three'};
str = strjoin(C)
```

Comment: Bah! you were one second before my edit! But you need to reshape I think? I get errors if I try yours as is

Comment: One could use transpose `S'` for that.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way, and IMHO cleanest way, is to make a "matrix" out of them:

```
s1 = 'bla';
s2 = 'blabla';
scat = [ s1, s2 ];
```

Comment: Seems like OP already has strings in form of cell array.

Comment: why do you use the scat variable ?

Comment: i mean the choice of the variable name is strange

Comment: s1 = string 1, s2 = string 2, scat = conCATenated string, creatively derived from the C function `strcat`. It's a three-line snippet, variable names weren't high on the priority list.

Answer (score 1):

I found a nice way:

```
S = {'file1'; 'file2'};
strjoin(S(:)', ' ')
```

Comment: I think @Mikhail's `strjoin(S')` is the correct solution for this specific problem.

Comment: What's the transpose for? I'm not near MATLAB at the moment; does `strjoin` require the cell array to be a row vector?

Comment: @EitanT ah I tried using `sprintf` but I didn't think of `{:}` to make it not a cell matrix!

Comment: @EitanT `strjoin` seems to only take `1xN` cell matrices...

Comment: so `S(:)'` is really what you need :) I've amended your answer, if you don't mind.

Comment: @EitanT Yeah that's better for the general case. Also you don't need the `' '` as that's the default, but might as well leave it in to make it clearer that you can change the delimiter.

Comment: I tried your option but it says:

Comment: Undefined function 'strjoin' for input arguments of type 'char'.